# How to run a werkzeug jsonrpc server in the background?

Tags: python, json, rpc, werkzeug

I'm using werkzeug to serve a jsonrpc service, but would like to have it run in the background in a separate thread. Think a gui app that runs a jsonrpc interface.

It is unclear to me as how to do this, in particular how to shutdown the server properly.

```
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from jsonrpc import JSONRPCResponseManager, dispatcher


@dispatcher.add_method
def hello(name):
    return "hello {0}".format(name)


@Request.application
def application(request):
    response = JSONRPCResponseManager.handle(request.data, dispatcher)
    return Response(response.json, mimetype='application/json')


run_simple("localhost", 8080, application)
```